# No .cat files generated when building an empty KMDF driver

Tags: visual-studio-2015, driver, kmdf

Hi I am trying to follow this tutorial [Write a universal Hello World driver (KMDF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver) provided by microsoft but I am stuck at number 6. I can't generate a .cat file inside KmdfHelloWorld/ARM/Debug. I could only see .cer, .inf, .pdb and .sys. There's also another directory named KmdfHelloWorld inside and it contains the same .inf and .sys file. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your Inf2Cat step is not being executed.  Make sure these settings are configured:

1. Open up the project settings and go to `Driver Signing`.
2. Change the Sign Mode to `Test Sign`.
3. Click the Test Certificate drop down and choose `<Create Test Certificate...>`
4. Set TimeStampServer to `None`